# How does the client get continues access to ressources after successfull basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

When a browser client successfully submits the username/email and password to the server and the next request the client retrives data from the server how is the client identified being successfully authenticated already?

I found this info:

"After the user enters credentials, the browser automatically sends them on subsequent requests to the same domain, for the duration of the session."

From where does the browser take the credentials for each subsequent request?

Do I have to actively save the credentials somewhere? How is the magic happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user's credentials have been authenticated by the server, the server returns an authorization token (commonly called auth token which is a long string made up of characters and numbers) which identify that the user has been authenticated and is valid. Every time, the user sends in his request, the request data will also contain this auth token (either as a cookie or added in to the request itself) which lets the server know that the client is valid. Because of this, the request is authenticated each time but not by using the actual username/password credentials.

Based on requirements, the auth token may be set to expire after a certain period (if there is not activity such as in banking applications).

Comment: I thought token authentication is something extra from basic authentication. So the token usage is always togehter with basic auth?

Comment: The first step is the basic authentication where the server checks against the database to see if there is a username/password match. If it does, then the server generates a unique authentication token (and it is unique for that specific credential and for that specific session - the length of the session is based on requirements). From here on, only the token is authenticated for each request. Passing the username/password in each step would just be extra overhead at this point and make the system more open to malicious intent. I hope that answers what you had in mind.

Comment: Also, the password is generally encrypted immediately within the request using an algorithm which only the server knows and can decrypt (some examples are base64, SHA, MD5 though most of them have their own implementation as it would be easy to decrypt these). The encryption/decryption process adds some overhead. This is why you might notice a slightly longer loading time when you first login but once you are in, navigating between pages is relatively quicker. Encryption/Decryption at each step would make the user experience a little slower.

Comment: When I google for basic authentication then the intention of the http specs is just to expect a username:password unencrypted in the Authorization Header but encoded with base64 and the scheme must be 'Basic' thats it. Now I ask myself from where (comittee?) comes the token idea of the subsequent request?

Comment: There is a design pattern called Interceptor (an example would be the interceptor found in Spring) that is commonly used to provide access to secure sites. Say for example you enter the url to your bank account page - what happens? You are redirected to the login page. This is because, the interceptor first intercepts this request and finds out that this request does not have an associated auth token and must hence be unauthenticated and hence redirects you to the login page. The same interceptor(generally) is setup to intercept requests to all the secure urls.

Comment: The interceptor basically makes the job simpler by simply just checking for a valid token. Since the token is associated with this specific session, it lives on the server as opposed to a database and hence validating it is much faster. Also the token is not encrypted (it is just a very long string). This altogether eliminates the need for encryption/decryption which makes the requests more lightweight and improves overall efficiency.

Comment: Without this system, it would be simple to find to find out what the payload is for your request when you access your account and then just play with this payload (if the request does not contain username/password, if it does contain then the system has a lot of overhead) and then gain access to other accounts. Twitter, for example, provides the web service api to the public for login. But there is no way you could crack an authorization token - it exists for a specific session and then destroyed off.

Comment: "Also the token is not encrypted (it is just a very long string)" Although many encrypt the token see json web token encrypted. ;-) Interceptor is a cool thing know it from angularjs which has one interceptor module :)